# Query without repeat with three tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have an oracle database with three tables. The first table has points with `ID, X, Y`, the second table has information about lines. The third table has connections between points (of first table) and lines (of second table).

Here is a small example

First table (POINTS):

```
ID_POINT        X       Y
1               -5      40.21
2               -3      41.23
3              -4.12    41.56
4             -7.34     42.68
```

Second table (LINES):

```
ID_LINE     NAME
100         LINE1
200         LINE2
```

The third table joins the LINES of second table with two points of the first table (CONNECTIONS)

```
ID      FROM    TO
1         1     100
2       100     2
3        2      100 
4       100     1
```

`FROM` and `TO` are `ID`s from first and second table. You can see in this example that POINT 1 is connected to LINE 100 and LINE 100 to POINT 2, so at the end LINE 100 connects POINT 1 to POINT 2.
You also can see the connection in the reverse order: POINT 2 with LINE 200 and LINE 100 with POINT 1.

I need to generate a Query in oracle that returns a table with all LINES and their coordinates without repetitions (so LINE 100 in this example should be once and not twice because i don't need to know the reverse order). For this example this table should be:

```
ID_LINE     X       Y       X1      Y2
100         -5      40.21   -3      41.23
```

This example only shows LINE 100 but there will be more lines.

I am using this query but I don't get it to work ok. Any idea?

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT LN.ID_LINE, 
               P1.X X,
               P1.Y Y,
               P2.X X,
               P2.Y Y,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID_LINE ORDER BY SRC1.FROM) ORDER
       FROM
            (
              SELECT *
              FROM LINES
            ) LN,
            CONNECTIONS SRC1,
            CONNECTIONS SRC2,
            POINTS P1,
            POINTS P1
        WHERE SRC1.TO(+)=LN.ID_LINE AND
              SRC2.FROM(+)=LN.ID_LINE AND
              P1.ID_POINT(+)=SRC1.FROM AND
              P2.ID_POINT(+)=SRC2.TO
    )
    WHERE ORDER=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by mentioning that this is a *very* bad database design. Let's say line 100 connects points 100 and 200. Then you'd get these connections:

```
ID      FROM    TO
1       100     100
2       100     200
3       200     100 
4       100     100
```

You see, you cannot technically see what is a point and what is a line in your third table. Moreover: A point that leads to a line that leads to a point??? No! A line *starts* with a point and *ends* with another. So instead of three tables you should have just two; the points table and a lines table as follows:

```
ID_LINE     NAME   FROM_ID_POINT  TO_ID_POINT
100         LINE1  1              2
200         LINE2  3              4
```

Another point is that you should not use keywords like FROM for column names.

However, even with the bad design given, the problem should be solvable. Let's assume an ID can always only be *either* a point *or* a line. So we must find out, what's a point and what's a line first. Thus we find all lines with all their points. Then we group by lines to find the two associated points (the min point and the max point associated; there should be just these two). Then join with the points table to get x and y.

```
select line.id_line, p1.x as x1, p1.y as y1, p2.x as x2, p2.y as y2
from
(
  select x.id_line, min(x.id_point) as id_start_point, max(x.id_point) as id_end_point
  from
  (
    select
      case when l.id is null then c.to else c.from end as id_line,
      case when l.id is null then c.from else c.to end as id_point
    from connections c
    left outer join lines l on l.id = c.from
  ) x
  group by x.id_line
) line
join points p1 on p1.id_point = line.id_start_point
join points p2 on p2.id_point = line.id_end_point;
```

Comment: Hi!Thanks for your answer!I don't like database desing but i can't change it >.<. In your query you do `group by x.id_line`. However in that subquery (x) you only return `line` and `point` so i can't use x.id_line >.<

Comment: You are right; I've corrected my answer. As you said, it was just confusing names, nothing more.

Comment: Hi guy! I also need to get all columns from table LINES, so I add in inner select `l.*` before from and `x.*` in the other select but i get an error `not a GROUP BY expresion`. Any idea for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this query will show each line just once. The trick is to always select the from and to id's in order in the case statement, so that the connections (id,p1,p2) and (id,p2,p1) will be treated as the same connection.

```
SELECT
    L.ID_LINE,
    L.NAME
    P1.X1,
    P1.Y1,
    P2.X1,
    P2.Y2
FROM    
    LINES L
    JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT
        L.ID_LINE,
        CASE(WHEN C1.TO > C2.FROM THEN C1.TO ELSE C2.FROM END) FROM_ID,
        CASE(WHEN C1.TO < C2.FROM THEN C1.TO ELSE c2.FROM END) TO_ID
      FROM
        LINES L
        JOIN CONNECTIONS C1 ON C1.FROM = L.ID_LINE
        JOIN CONNECTIONS C2 ON C2.TO = L.ID_LINE
   ) t1 ON t1.LINE_ID = L.LINE_ID
   JOIN POINTS P1 ON P1.ID_POINT = t1.FROM_ID 
   JOIN POINTS P2 ON P2.ID_POINT = t1.TO_ID
```